# Is it possible to use orange software as web-service

Tags: .net, web-services, text-mining, orange

Is it possible to use orange software as web-service then use it with .Net framework? i want to use it on my website with database it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Orange is an interactive desktop application and was not intended to be used as a web service where all the interactivity and visualizations would be useless.

Comment: However, hypothetically it could be invoked and its produced results could be embedded to a web service.